# Display website background underneath transparent navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I need my background-image to display underneath my website transparent navigation bar. The image is located under the .header div

http://prntscr.com/p2moi0

```
        <!Navigation Bar>
        <nav>
            <div class="navigation-bar">
                <img class="logo" src="images/logo-black.png">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a href="#">faq</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="header">
            <h1>Website development<br> made easy</h1>
            <h3>Not just a business but a reliable business partner</h3>
            <button type="button" class="button button-1">get started</button>
            <button type="button" class="button button-2">get a quote</button>
        </div>
    </body>
```

```
.header{
    background-image: url('images/main-background-header.png');
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center; 

    .navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it work add `background div` to your `header` with `height` equal to `full header height` `+` your `navbar height`
. your `navbar` should have a `z-index` of -1 and the `background` div should have an `absolute` position relative to the `header`:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.image{
background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800');
    background-position: center;
    height: calc(100% + 80px);
  width:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
    top: -80px;
    text-align: center; 
}
    .navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    }

.header{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 0px;
}
.navigation-bar{
  display:flex;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  align-items:center;
}
.navigation-bar img{
  margin-right:10px;
}

.navigation-bar a{
  margin-left:10px;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.navigation-bar a:hover{
  background-color:white;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
       <!Navigation Bar>
        <nav>
            <div class="navigation-bar">
                <img class="logo" src="images/logo-black.png">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a href="#">faq</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="header">
          <div class="image"></div>
            <h1>Website development<br> made easy</h1>
            <h3>Not just a business but a reliable business partner</h3>
            <button type="button" class="button button-1">get started</button>
            <button type="button" class="button button-2">get a quote</button>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: When I add a margin / padding to the header text it still makes white space on-top http://prntscr.com/p2n394

Comment: margin will add space because is not part of your header height but padding not it's included in height !  to cover the margin  space you need to add it to the background `height` and decrease it from the `top` position!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

HTML

```
     <div class="banner"> 
<nav>
            <div class="navigation-bar">
                <img class="logo" src="images/logo-black.png">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a href="#">faq</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="header">
            <h1>Website development<br> made easy</h1>
            <h3>Not just a business but a reliable business partner</h3>
            <button type="button" class="button button-1">get started</button>
            <button type="button" class="button button-2">get a quote</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
  .banner{
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-73.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center; 
    padding:40px 0;
    }

    .nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: So the navigation bar should be transparent and the header/banner background image needs to be displayed underneath the navigation bar as well.

Comment: Thank you! I already found a solution. Thanks for trying tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the elements margin and it will work. That is done by making every element 
**margin:0**.
See the example bellow:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}

.header{
  background-image: url('https://i.cbc.ca/1.4955357.1545355364!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_780/man-works-late-at-office-computer.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center; 
}
    .navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    }
```

```html
  <nav>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo-black.png">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a href="#">faq</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="header">
    <h1>Website development<br> made easy</h1>
    <h3>Not just a business but a reliable business partner</h3>
    <button type="button" class="button button-1">get started</button>
    <button type="button" class="button button-2">get a quote</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've already found a solution, thank you for your help!